# Unable to send email to an Office 365 team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, team-sites, office-365-groups

I have created a public office 365 team site, which provision a sharepoint modern team site. and i gave the group an email address `HR.Team@ourcompany.com`, as follow:-
[image]

[image]

But when i try to send an email to `HR.Team@ourcompany.com`, i thought that group members will receive an email, but i got a delivery fail

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
HR.Team@ourcompany.com (HR.Team@ourcompany.com)
The email address that you entered couldn't be found.
```

so can anyone advice on this please? do we need to do extra steps to allow sending emails to the  team site email address? which i assume will send an email to the team site members?

Comment: Send it to `HRTeamourcompanycom@ourcompany.com` and check. It needs to be the value in the `Group email address` field as per your image

Comment: @GautamSheth now i hover over the Group title where i got a popup with the group email address, and you are correct the email address is `HRTeamourcompanycom@ourcompany.com` but when i try to send an email to it, i received this email  `The email address that you entered couldn't be found. 550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found ##`

Comment: if you have provisioned right now, would suggest that you wait a few mins. It takes some time to provision the mailbox. Try after a few mins

Comment: @GautamSheth so we do not need to set the mail box separately ? it should be created for us, and since we are on office 365 so that email will have `onmicrosoft.com` in it ? is this correct? second point, if we already have a distribution list email address, can i use it inside the team site ?

Comment: 1) No 2) yes will have `onmicrosoft.com` domain 3)  You will need to add DL to that O365 group and not SharePoint group because the group manages the permissions. Not sure if you will be able to send mail to DL in group, havent tested that

Comment: @Gautam now the problem is that we need the team site email to be without `onmicrosoft` as follow `HR.Team@ourcompnay.com`. but if i create the team site using the sharepoint admin ui, the group email will be `HR.Team@ourcompnay.onmicrosoft.com` so will we be able to change this?

Comment: If you are trying to send email from outside domain mailbox i.e. from external user. You need to add that external user to team site. Once added, that user can send email to group email which will receive to all members.

Comment: @BhaskarDhone no i do not want them to be external.. now our customer have some users ' emails ending with `@ourcompnay.onmicrosoft.com`  while other ending with `@ourcompnay.com` (without `onmicrosoft`).. now my question is if i can configure the new team site's email to be `HR.Team@ourcompnay.com` without `onmicrosoft` ...as by defualt when we create a new team site its email will end with `@ourcompnay.onmicrosoft.com` ... did you get my point ?

Comment: @Gautam now i tried sending emails to the group created  2 hours ago, and still i got delivery failure email. also i search for the group email address inside Users >> Active Users.. but i could not find it.

Comment: @BhaskarDhone also i am facing a strange scenario. now when i first create the Team site  it got this email address with `onmicrosoft` inside it as follow `HR.Team@ourcompnay.onmicrosoft.com`. now (after around 2 hours) i check the team site email and seem the `onmicrosoft` inside it WAS REMOVED automatically !! so the email now is `HR.Team@ourcompnay.com`. so now sure how the `onmicrosoft` got removed? second problem is that if i send an email to `HR.Team@ourcompnay.com` or to `HR.Team@ourcompnay.onmicrosoft.com`, i will receive a delivery failure email.. so can you advice on this ?